# How to call Azure function from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I currently have deployed an Azure function used to get an AD token.

Function:
https://getadtokennet.azurewebsites.net/api/getadtokennet

Request header:

x-functions-key = {key}

How can I call this function from my Kotlin app?

This is the way I call it from Javascript

```
function getTokenAzure(onsuccess, onerror) {
    var tokenUrl = 'https://getadtokennet.azurewebsites.net/api/getadtokennet';

    $.ajax(tokenUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("x-functions-key", "function key");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            onsuccess(data);
            console.log('token: ' + data.token);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var failureMessage = "GetToken error: " + status + " - " + error;
            onerror(failureMessage);
            console.log(failureMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, here it is.

```
   fun getToken(): String {

        val tokenUrl = URL("https://getadtokennet.azurewebsites.net/api/getadtokennet")

        val connection = tokenUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.requestMethod = "POST"
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-functions-key", "function key")
        connection.doOutput = true

        val responseCode = connection.responseCode

        if (responseCode == HTTP_OK) {
            val readerIn = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream))
            var inputLine = readerIn.readLine()
            val response = StringBuffer()

            do {
                response.append(inputLine)
            } while (inputLine.length < 0)
            readerIn.close()

            // Return token
            return response.toString()
        } else {
            val responseError = Error(code = "BadRequest", message = "There was an error getting the token.")
            throw IOException(responseError.toString())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In IntelliJ IDEA, select **Create New Project**.
2. In the **New Project** window, select **Maven** from the left pane.
3. Select the **Create from archetype** check box, and then select **Add Archetype** for the [azure-functions-kotlin-archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-functions-kotlin-archetype).
4. In the **Add Archetype** window, complete the fields as follows:

   - *GroupId*: com.microsoft.azure
   - *ArtifactId*: azure-functions-kotlin-archetype
   - *Version*: Use the latest version from [the central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-functions-kotlin-archetype) [image: Create a Maven project from archetype in IntelliJ IDEA]
5. Select **OK**, and then select **Next**.
6. Enter your details for current project, and select **Finish**.

For complete information refer to the below links which has same information.

[Kotlin Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-kotlin-intellij)  and [Running Kotlin in Azure Functions](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/11/16/running-kotlin-in-azure-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already have the azure function, just want to call it from my Kotlin app, I'm using Android studio.